# joined objects upon duplicating

Tags: physics

Here in the picture. I clicked only one face and for some reason the other faces highlighted too. And when I want to highlight/click the other faces/vert/edge it wont highlight. I need to click the original face on original object so highlight others too and I don't want that[image]

Comment: Hello :). These looks like *linked* duplicates (Alt+D). To make simple duplicates use *Shift+D*. To select other objects, you need to switch to *Object mode*.

Comment: Ow god you really help me thanks a lot